# Use awk to find letters and print results

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I've got a student.txt file that contains some columns (name, surname, c1, c2, c3, c4) like this

```
Jack Poki theo 100 49 38
.
```

15 registries like the above, I want with awk to find the students that their name starts with J or M and printf only their surnames and names

Comment: I can't help but feel like this question was written in a hurry...Please can you [edit] to tidy it up? You need to show us a sample of your input, the desired output and describe where you're stuck.

Comment: A small step in the right direction?

Comment: Post a FEW lines of sample input, not just 1, and the expected output given that input. Include edge cases like hyphenated names like Smith-Whitley and names that start with `Mc` and `O'` like McGonigal and O'Grady. Clarify if "their name" means their fist or last name or both. How about middle name? Can J or M occur in other fields? And format it properly using the `{}` button on the editor.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I think you are looking for this:

```
awk '/^[JM]/{print $1,$2}' i_ve_got_an_vi_edirtor_with_some_collums.file
```

#### update

> Now i need the same but only for students that the surname starts from [A-D]

```
awk '$2~/^[A-D]/{print $1,$2}' i_ve_got_an_vi_edirtor_with_some_collums.file
```

Comment: Now i need the same but only for students that the surname starts from [A-D]

Comment: and the onion peeling begins. sigh....

Comment: @JHk1821 updated in answer. you will get this two for free, 5$ for each further requirement. ^_^

Comment: I think you are looking for a bunch of downvotes. You should know better by now than to help vampires like this guy.

Comment: @Puppy for the answer itself, I don't understand why I got the downvote. Because I helped him? Or the answer is bad?

Comment: for finding the students with c2 and c3 > 90 ? :P (Sorry for this q's but they make us to do some exercise in uni without explain us... )

Comment: @Kent: The first directly means the second.

Comment: @JHk1821 pls read my comment above.

Comment: @JHk1821 Learn how to do it then, this is easily enough of a starting point. Why not actually learn how to do things, this is super basic...

Comment: 5$ for further requriment i thought that forum was for helping not for paying to help you... no thank you... @123 if u have any manual that can help because myself cant find...

Comment: @JHk1821 have you considered trying to understand the solutions that you have been provided, rather than just making a series of very similar requests? If you don't understand the code, then ask for clarification.

Comment: @JHk1821 the document you need to read is the book Effective Awk Programming, 4th Edition, by Arnold Robbins. Also the forum IS to **help**, not to do all the work for you.

Comment: @JHk1821 5$ was just kidding.  It seems that you didn't understand those comments.

Comment: @kent i was thought that u are kidding but from this guys that telling me all this i can w8 for sth like it... if u want and you have time you can give me some info in order to communicate with you away from these guys ***$*...

Comment: I suggest that you do what @EdMorton said, read some tutorial about awk. If you don't want to do that, try to guess what does `$1or $2` mean, what would be `$3, $4?` what could be the expression of `c2 and c3 > 90`?... do some test. I cannot give further help. sorry.

Comment: @JHk1821 Summary: You posted a poorly constructed question, and ignored the advice given on how to make it better. You got an answer despite that and asked a second question in the comments. You got an answer to that and asked a third question in the comments. People suggested you try to learn from the answers you already got. You told us it was school work and asked what document you could read to learn from and you were given that. You then posted a rant about people being mean to you and asked if the person whos been supplying you answers could talk to you `away from these guys`. Good luck!